# 28 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, ads

[image]

28 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Using GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.6.0.
This working in my device and simulator without problem and i'm getting ads on banner, but when i archive to update in store it's showing this error, Please help any one already spent 1 day. 
Using Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: update XCode, this can solve the issue.

Comment: Try after remove -ObjC from Other Linker Flags,

Comment: If i remove -ObjC means ads not getting work